# flash player doesn't work in explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, flash

Flash player doesn't work in explorer 8 ( Windows 7 64 bit ) , I can't load the pages which use adobe flash. If I disable flash plug-in, the pages can be loaded but naturally without flash animations . It doesn't make auto updates. Chrome works without problem. What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to IE9 didn't work but  I updated later Flash. Version 11.1.102 works properly on IE9

Answer (score 0):

You could try upgrading to a more recent version of Internet Explorer. IE8 is over six years old.